# XML transformation with XSL

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon, xalan

I want to transfer XML file to other XML with XSLT. I want to do transformation because XML file isn't pure tree-structured document.

Here's my file before:

```
<uglyStartTag></uglyStartTag>
    <name>content</name>
<uglyEndTag></uglyEndTag>
```

or

```
<uglyStartTag/>
    <name>content</name>
<uglyEndTag/>
```

Here's my file after:

```
<beautyTag>
    <name>content</name>
</beautyTag>
```

How can I do it? I'm not familiarized with XSLT so I will be thankful for any advice.

Comment: Are you aware, that what you have is not well-formed xml. This might even lead to xslt not working at all.

Comment: `XML file isn't pure tree-structured` isn't it contradictory?

Comment: XML file is correctly formed with XML standard, but for storing one data type I have two tags: opening `uglyStartTag` and ending `uglyEndTag`. There should be one tag, like `beautyTag`

Comment: @Kowser, As you can see data is never stored inside of `<uglyStartTag></uglyStartTag>` or `<uglyEndTag></uglyEndTag>`. There's no possibility that for example `uglyStartTag` will store like: `<uglyEndTag>**some data**</uglyEndTag>`. So it isn't pure tree-structured  standard

Comment: the point is the first example is **not** valid XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match=
      "node()[preceding-sibling::uglyStartTag
            and
              following-sibling::uglyEndTag
              ][1]">
      <beautyTag>
        <xsl:copy-of select=
         "../node()[preceding-sibling::uglyStartTag
                  and
                    following-sibling::uglyEndTag
                   ]
         "/>
      </beautyTag>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (provided by the OP in a comment):

```
<t>
    <uglyStartTag />
    <name>dgsdgsdgsdg</name>
    <uglyEndTag />
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<beautyTag>
   <name>dgsdgsdgsdg</name>
</beautyTag>
```

Comment: Could you tell me what's wrong when I'm trying use that XSLT with `<t><uglyStartTag />
  <name>dgsdgsdgsdg</name>
 <uglyEndTag /></t>`. The output is `<beautyTag>dgsdgsdgsdg</beautyTag>`. I would like to have `<beautyTag><name>dgsdgsdgsdg</name></beautyTag>`

Comment: @bontade, You didn't specify such requirement in the question. "content" is just a string. Please, edit and update the question. I will shortly update my answer.

Comment: @bontade, I edited this answer and now it processes your new XML document in the wanted way.